# Application getting abruptly closed on longer usage

Tags: angular, typescript-typings

My application is getting abruptly closed on longer usage , and getting following error :

```
{"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 9.3.5 (13G36)","build_version":"1.3.0","timestamp":"2017-05-30 18:35:53.53 +0530","app_name":" *****","bundleID":" *****","name":" *****","is_first_party":false,"app_version":"1.3.0","share_with_app_devs":false,"slice_uuid":"4ee66c3b-8162-3e70-8a7a-d54bb7aa5ef1","adam_id":0}
    Incident Identifier: 9A56DB2D-5F51-4FD4-9200-0B4874EDFBE0
    CrashReporter Key:   d58d14c44f0e55de4b5c3b39e41bf1e4d450f453
    Hardware Model:      iPad2,5
    Process:             *****[2770]
    Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/FEBF762B-57F0-4EB2-9BCE-60E2A0C4D1DC/LotSmart.app/LotSmart
    Identifier:          com.lojack.mobile.lotsmart
    Version:             1.3.0 (1.3.0)
    Code Type:           ARM (Native)
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]

    Date/Time:           2017-05-30 18:35:52.52 +0530
    Launch Time:         2017-05-30 17:28:43.43 +0530
    OS Version:          iOS 9.3.5 (13G36)
    Report Version:      104

    Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
    Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xbbadbeef
    Triggered by Thread:  0

    Filtered syslog:
    None found

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    ------
    ----
    -----
    Error Formulating Crash Report:
    Failed while requesting activity/breadcrumb diagnostics
```

Comment: please find the Crash logs

Comment: A `SIGSEGV` indicates a problem in some native code like dereferencing an invalid pointer. Also the failing address `0xbbadbeef` looks like it has been set deliberately to an invalid value.